# Check if a user exists in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working with SQL Server 2012. I want to check if a user exists before adding it to a database.

This is what I have tested:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name 
                FROM [sys].[server_principals]
                WHERE name = N'IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool')
Begin
    CREATE USER [IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool] 
    FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
end
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool]
GO
```

But, this code `SELECT name FROM [sys].[server_principals]` doesn't return if that user exists in `MyDatabase`.

How can I check if an user exists in `MyDatabase`?

Comment: Keep in mind that the sys.database_principals contains roles and users together, so one must not forget to at filter the users. I am updating the final query against the currently marked answer for easy reference.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [`sys.database_principals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql) instead of `sys.server_principals`.

So the final query would look like this (accounting for the user filter):

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name]
                FROM [sys].[database_principals]
                WHERE [type] = N'S' AND [name] = N'IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool')
Begin
    CREATE USER [IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool] 
    FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
end
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool]
GO
```

Comment: A quick way to get this (or other object existence checking) is to right click on a database object and select "DROP And CREATE TO" which will generate the proper IF NOT EXISTS clause.

Comment: @LowlyDBA it doesn't work in MSSQL 2017 with SSMS 18.5. There is no 'if not exists' just a pure drop and create.

Comment: To account for AD accounts I would change it to: WHERE [type] IN (N'S',N'U')

Comment: @Asher You have to enable in the 'check for object existence' in scripting settings.

Comment: @Chris Aldrich: Do you know how to do this for multiple users? (e.g., adding 10 users to 10 separate databases)?

Answer (score 27):

I use SUSER_ID() and USER_ID() for this kind of things:

```
-- Check SQL Server Login
IF SUSER_ID('SomeLogin') IS NULL
    CREATE LOGIN SomeLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'SomePassword';

-- Check database user
IF USER_ID('SomeUser') IS NULL
    CREATE USER SomeUser FOR LOGIN SomeLogin;
```

Comment: As per Microsoft's recommendation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-id-transact-sql], the USER_ID wil be phased out in the near future and the recommended function to use instead is DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/database-principal-id-transact-sql]

Comment: Link is broken. New link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-id-transact-sql

Answer (score 18):

Further refinement as this would make a more optimal read-

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool] 
    FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
END
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApi AppPool]
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using resistered servers you can check many servers at once and return a true/false with:

```
SELECT @@servername,    
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'LoginName') THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS YesNo
```

Comment: You may want to update your answer to mention `database_principals` instead of `server_principals` - check the question - it's about users at the *database* level.